# Prevent text from overflowing down

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'd like the text to go up instead of going down out of the div, and `overflow: auto;` or anything that cuts the text is a no go. Thank you.

Here is an image of my problem.
[image: overflow]

Comment: What's the code?

Comment: I just fixed it, didn't think anyone would respond

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be solved by adding a `margin` to the text.

```
position : relative;
margin-top : -5px;
```

You can change the value of `margin-top` as you want.

Or you can keep your text inside the `div`. This will do it better than above answer.

```
<div>
    <h3> Your text </h3>
</div>
```